# Change page inside a frame from another class

Tags: c#, frame, uwp

So I have tried following [UWP Accessing Frame for page navigation through Usercontrol an Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32254859/uwp-accessing-frame-for-page-navigation-through-usercontrol-an-object/32262029#comment55025160_32262029)
But I get a nullpointer.

I have a mainpage with a splitview, frame and a hamburger menu. From here I control the pages that are loaded into the frame.
I also have a profile view and i want to invoke a new view when the user clicks a button. Let me add the code:

MainPage:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page

{

    Profile profile = new Profile();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(Financial));
        BackButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        Title.Margin = new Thickness(68,0,0,0);

        profile.OnNavigateParentReady += OnCreateUser;

    }

....



    public void OnCreateUser(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MySplitView.Content != null)
            ((Frame)MySplitView.Content).Navigate(typeof(CreateUser));
        Title.Text = "Create User";
        BackButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Title.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);

    }

}
```

And profile:

```
public sealed partial class Profile : Page

{

    public delegate void MyEventHandler(object source, RoutedEventArgs e);

    public event MyEventHandler OnNavigateParentReady;


    private string _profileName;
    private string _password;

    private Dictionary<string, string> usersDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public Profile()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        usersDictionary.Add("Casper", "12345");
    }

    private void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _profileName = ProfileName.Text;
        _password = PasswordBox.Password;

        if (usersDictionary.ContainsKey(_profileName))
        {
            if (usersDictionary[_profileName] == _password)
            {
                ProfileName.Text = "LOGIN SUCCES!";
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    private void CreateUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnNavigateParentReady(sender, e);
    }
}
```

I can change the frame with no problem using `Frame.navigate` but I want to edit the title as well as margin and all other `OnCreateUser` does. How do I go about that?

EDIT: I should say that i get a nullpointer on this line: `OnNavigateParentReady(sender, e);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That null reference exception is thrown because the `OnNavigateParentReady` event has no listeners yet, when the `Click` event is invoked on your `CreateUser` control. You should try the following:

```
if (OnNavigateParentReady != null)
{
    OnNavigateParentReady(sender, e);
}
```

Also, the `profile` object that you create inside the `MainPage` class - where is it used? Is it ever shown anywhere? It seems as if that object is not the one showing up in your app. Instead, some other instance of `Profile` is being used!

The `profile` member field of your `MainPage` class is probably not the `Page` actually showing up when you navigate. Try setting an event listener on the `Profile` page object actually being displayed.

Comment: It resolved the crash but the frame doesnt change, seems like the method is not called properly.

Comment: It is used here: `profile.OnNavigateParentReady += OnCreateUser;`

Comment: I am fairly new to C# So not quite sure how to set event listeners?

Comment: That is probably the only reference to that instance. The object you create is not the one being displayed! You are actually setting the event listener correctly with `profile.OnNavigateParentReady += OnCreateUser;` - you are just setting it on the wrong object. You should read up on classes and instances to get this right. It might not be easy to explain in a StackOverflow comment...